# AWS: Remove S3 files not accessed for a long time via cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I wonder is it possible to configure using AWS build-in lifecylce capability if certain files were not accessed (via pubic Cloudfront distribution) for a certain period of time, they would be auto-deleted eventually.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52963853/identifying-and-deleting-s3-objects-that-are-not-being-accessed

Comment: @Tim thanks, I believe the link contains the answer.